# Cannot get content of specific div

Tags: regex

I've this html page. I'm trying to extract the following information of this div:

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="container left">    
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/teams/belarus/fc-bate-borisov/200/">
        <img src="http://cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/200.png" alt="FC BATE Borisov" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container middle">
    <div class="details clearfix">
      <dl>
        <dt>Gara</dt>
        <dd><a href="/national/belarus/premier-league/2016/regular-season/r34862/">Premier League</a></dd>

        <dt>Data</dt>
        <dd><a href="/matches/2016/06/25/"><span class='timestamp' data-value='1466877600' data-format='d mmmm yyyy'>25 giugno 2016</span></a></dd>

        <dt>Game week</dt>
        <dd>14</dd>

        <dt>calcio di inizio</dt>
        <dd>
          <span class='timestamp' data-value='1466877600' data-format='HH:MM'>20:00</span>
          (<span class="game-minute">FP'</span>)
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>

    <div class="details clearfix">
      <dl>
        <dt>Stadio</dt>
        <dd><a href="venue/">Borisov Arena (Barysaw (Borisov))</a></dd>

      </dl>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container right">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/teams/belarus/fc-vitebsk/204/">
        <img src="http://cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/204.png" alt="FC Vitebsk" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in particular the tab `calcio di inizio - game week - stadio`

Actually I've tried this regex: `<div[^<>]*class="clearfix"[^<>]*>(?<content>.*?)`

but when I test it on https://regex101.com/ I can't run the regex.
I think that the class of the div is associated on multiple divs, so this could be the problem.

And also the  doesn't have any class for take it, any idea?

Comment: Have you considered using a proper HTML parser instead?

Comment: Please see the [standard answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) for why not to do it with regexes.  Now, to answer your question, you might use something like [Xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html).  Perhaps like this: `xidel -e '//div[@class="clearfix"]' file.html`.

Comment: which do you suggest? I'm on .net

Answer (score 0):

If you add an id to the div you want to get the contents of (for example "myDiv"), you could run the following javascript function to return it's HTML contents:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML
```

I am not exactly sure if this is what you want, since its not regex, but if so, I hope this helps!

Comment: How are you sure it is a Javascript question?

Comment: I'm not, but since the author is using html, it is likely that he is also using js. I may be wrong